# xpath: select/count words

Tags: xpath

HTML code:
`<h1 id="title" class="a-size"><span>Web page title - web page title</span></h1>`

from my xpath code:

`".//h1[@id='title']/span"`

I want to select only the first 3 words.

Comment: With XPath questions you should always say which XPath version you are using. This one is hard or impossible to achieve with XPath 1.0, which is what people tend to be using unless they install a third-party library offering XPath 2.0 or 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is a word can get rather complicated, depending on the languages but if you have XPath 2.0 or later (the current version is 3.1) you might want to try

```
//h1[@id='title']/span/tokenize(., '\s+')[position() le 3]
```

which, for your example input, should [give a sequence of three strings](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=%2F%2Fh1%5B%40id%3D%27title%27%5D%2Fspan%2Ftokenize%28.%2C%20%27%5Cs%2B%27%29%5Bposition%28%29%20le%203%5D&input=%3Ch1%20id%3D%22title%22%20class%3D%22a-size%22%3E%3Cspan%3EWeb%20page%20title%20-%20web%20page%20title%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fh1%3E&input-type=HTML) `Web`, `page`, `title`.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first 3 words from the given sample (XPath 1.0)

```
substring-before(.//h1[@id='title']/span," - ")
```

Simple test on command line

```
xmllint --xpath 'substring-before(.//h1[@id="title"]/span," - ")' tmp.html
Web page title
```